# Why was this question tagged as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Okay, so I am very confused and possibly for a simply reason, but to me this makes no sense.

***The Problem:***

The question [Muggle Borns and Social Workers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50063/muggle-borns-and-social-workers)  tagged Feb 14 is marked as a Duplicate Nov 25 of [What's the “official” explanation for Harry's (and everyone else's) absence from muggle school?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73349/whats-the-official-explanation-for-harrys-and-everyone-elses-absence-from) which was asked Nov 24.

BUT

Since the question "Muggle Borns and Social Workers" comes first shouldn't that be the original and the second question be the duplicate?

I am very confused and don't know how to explain this could somebody please shed some light or is this a topic for Meta Stack Exchange?

### My major Problem is:

- How can the first question be a duplicate of the second? Especially when it came nearly 6 months before?

Did I miss some required reading from the Help Center about duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Should we always close the newer question as the duplicate?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4744/19561),  it's not necessarily the newer question that gets closed.

Usually it is, but there are a number of reasons why the newer question is preferred to the older. In this case, I flagged the newer as a duplicate, but before it got closed, it ended up on the Hot Network Questions list. That made it get a lot of attention and answers, so that made one of the mods decide to close the older.

Since I think the old question has some good quality answers as well, I'd like to suggest merging, but I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I closed them that way because looking at the two questions, the more recent one seemed higher-quality, and it got *way* more attention.

Comment: I would say is that even fair, but IDK. Is this a common practice? I didn't read anything about this.

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock Yes, when one question is significantly better than the other, it is common and encouraged that that one is the dupe target regardless of the relative ages.

Comment: @Kevin But what about just merging content. Doesn't that make sense, this current practice just seems like rewarding duplicates. People might just write a duplicate, but add new info. Couldn't this be a problem?

Comment: The reason #2 got more attention was because it was unfairly singled out for "Network Hot Questions". As usual, way-undeservedly inflating its stats completely out of proportion to the quality of its answers.

Comment: @DVK Yes, yes, we get it, you hate the NHQ list.