# How can a 3-year-old question be a duplicate a new one?

Tags: discussion

3 years ago, there was this question:

[Help identifying a sci-fi book with short stories about portals](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21847/help-identifying-a-sci-fi-book-with-short-stories-about-portals)

And today there was this question:

[Short story collection about Transporter “Doors”](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100407/short-story-collection-about-transporter-doors)

The new question was a duplicate of the old one, but the old one got closed as the duplicate? Shouldn't the new one be closed instead?

Comment: Good question...

Comment: The worse question is always a duplicate of the better question.

Answer (score 5):

This happens sometimes. The decision of which to make the duplicate is based on which question is better, more inclusive, etc. It can also matter if the newer question already has a better answer than the older.

In this case, the newer question and its newer answer has slightly more information than the older.

See also: [Should we always close the newer question as the duplicate?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/should-we-always-close-the-newer-question-as-the-duplicate)

Comment: I've expanded my answer to provide more information. I had to get a hold of the book first.