# Can I ask a duplicate question based on requesting new information?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

So a few days ago I asked [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105575/watchmen-book-ending-versus-movie-ending) regarding the ending differences of the Watchmen book and movie and it was marked as duplicate to a question from 2011 (answered 2011).

First off, I'm not disagreeing with the duplicate tag.

So, I had a question about the ending, one that I hoped could be solved by a quote from a cast member or crew member. In the original question, one of the answers stated that there was no such quote to be found (2011). Now, my question (and then later added to the original) had an answer that DID have such a quote. Funny enough, the quote was from 2009, but this bears little importance. What is important is that it was believed there was no information, and I believed there could be some given the 4 year gap.

So, how do I ask a question in hopes of finding new information that was not available in an old answer?

Can I do that? Should I comment on an old question? Do I ask anyway, knowing it will get marked duplicate so as to point at the original and get new answers?

Comment: i'd suggest posting a bounty on the old question with the reason that the existing answers are outdated or that you're looking for an authoritative source

Comment: Not sure why this meta post was downvoted: surely it's a perfectly reasonable question to ask?

Comment: @randal'thor I can handle it :)

Answer (score 10):

You have a few different options

### Bounty

This is the preferred way: [post a bounty](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) on the older question. This automatically bumps the question to the top of the front page and puts it in the [featured questions tab](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured), making it much more visible and gives a little extra incentive to prospective answerers. There are a variety of bounty reasons you can choose from, and the one you pick will appear in the notice under the question:

[image]

I would think that **Authoritative reference**, **Canonical answer**, or **Improve details** would all be good reasons for your case. You can also (optionally) add a custom message to the bounty notice, which can be helpful for adding context.

The main downside here is that the ability to post a bounty is restricted to users with at least 75 rep. And, of course, that you're sacrificing some of your own hard-earned reputation.

### Chat

If you don't want to (or can't) post a bounty, you can also ask the Lovecraftian monstrosity that dwells in the [Mos Eisley chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198). If you ask at a time when many people are active (which seems to be most of the time, though as an irregular denizen I'm not an authority), there's a good chance that somebody in there will be able to find the answer.

### Just Ask It

This is a slightly more controversial option, and I wouldn't advise it in this case, but I should point out that it's not *necessarily* a bad thing to ask a question that's been asked before. We do occasionally [close older questions as duplicates of newer ones](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/should-we-always-close-the-newer-question-as-the-duplicate), but it's somewhat less common.

In general, you should only take this option under two circumstances:

1. Your version of the question is demonstrably better-quality
2. Your question is a superset of the older question (but be careful it's not Too Broad)

In either case, you may have to fight hard to not have your question be closed.

Comment: We are all seeing. We are all knowing. We are one and we are strawberry flavoured. There's always someone hanging around in Mos Eisley and most of us can give you solid advice or even answers :).

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say.

Comment: "a time when many people are active (which seems to be most of the time" - except the small hours in US time, say around 0700-1300 UTC.

Comment: Good to know, didn't know I could put a bounty on someone else's question