# Star Wars question is an exact duplicate of old question asked before Legends. Retag old question or add new answer to old and mark new as dupe?

Tags: duplicate-questions, discussion

The new question [Are there any technological defences against the Force?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/150097/13217) has the tags [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) and [the-force](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-force). However,
[Can flow of force be disturbed with technology?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10077/13217) is an exact duplicate and also has the tags [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) and [the-force](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-force) (as well as [video-games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games), which is probably unnecessary).

The trouble is that the second question was asked in 2012 before the Legends/Disney split and the existing answer is Legends-only. I'm not sure what to do in this situation. Should we:

1. Mark the new question as a duplicate and add a Disney canon answer to the old question?
2. Keep both questions open and retag the old question as [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars), [star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends), [the-force](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-force). Thus the only difference between the two questions is the addition of the Legends tag?

**Related:** [How should we handle "obsolete" answers to old questions (e.g. pre-Disney canon Star Wars questions)?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10422/13217) in which a pre-Disney canon question was never retagged as [star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends), but was given a Disney canon answer that contradicted Legends answers. The consensus was to keep the question open without retagging and just upvote the Disney canon answer.

Comment: Slap a bounty on it. The is precisely what the "current answers are out of date" is for.

Comment: Yes, the old question.

Comment: @Valorum So you would advocate marking the new one as a duplicate and adding a Disney canon answer to the old question (adding a bounty as encouragement if desired). Is that correct?

Comment: I (or someone else) could easily write a canon answer to the old question.

Comment: @Thunderforge - Yes. And I'm really at a loss why this needs to be asked

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Mark it as duplicate

It’s not worth it to have two different questions for two different canons. Would we want one question about the *Doctor Who* television series, another about the audio serials, and a third about written works, all asking (for example) whether the Doctor is really half-human? Would we want one question about *The Cursed Child* and another about the main Harry Potter series, asking whether Voldemort had any children? Better not to have two or three identical questions with slightly different flavors of continuity, and that differ only mainly in the tags that people have attached. Most people are not even going to look at the tags, which could lead to a great deal of confusion.

More to the point, we aren’t generally in the habit of asking new questions when an old question contains information that’s out-of-date or obsolete. If the answers to a duplicate question aren’t satisfactory enough, we have several options:

1. **Post a bounty on the old question**, with the reason “The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.”
2. **Write a new answer** that takes into account only new Disney canon information, or that takes into account both Disney canon and Legends.
3. **Leave a comment** suggesting some changes on one or more of the existing answers.