# Dupe, but mine was first

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I asked [How did Maz Kanata acquire Luke's lightsaber?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111023/how-did-maz-kanata-acquire-this-weapon?noredirect=1#comment264921_111023) and then, 12 hours later, JMFB asked [In Star Wars: "The Force Awakens," how could this lightsaber have turned up where it did?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111121/what-are-the-origins-of-this-weapon) which I, like a few others, believed was a duplicate of mine.

But then someone voted to close *my* question as a duplicate, even though mine was first. I honestly believe my question is clearer and the answers on both questions are saying the same thing so far.

I read [Should we always close the newer question as the duplicate?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/should-we-always-close-the-newer-question-as-the-duplicate) but I guess I still don't know what I should do.

It shows this on my question
[image]
and I don't know what to do since I *don't think* my question's different, it's just that I think the *other one* should be closed.

Comment: Objectively speaking, why do you think the other one should be closed over yours? What additional information or context does your question provide that the other doesn't?

Comment: Besides being 1st, I feel mine is clearer and the answers on both say the same thing so far. :) Right now the other one says "duplicate" and looks like people are trying to reopen it. Also mine has some close votes, which is silly- why close both? lol

Comment: @RedCaio The close votes on your question just haven't aged away yet; they will after a few days (I believe it's 4 days after the last vote was cast). I wouldn't worry about it too much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Let the community decide.

Usually with dupes the newest one is normally closed but there are exceptions, these exceptions occur when the newer question receives a better answer than the older question or for some other extenuating circumstance.

As the author there's really nothing you can do and you shouldn't take it personally at all this overlap is bound to happen with everyone asking the same question from the new movie and phrasing it differently due to spoilers.

It's possible that people prefer the new question because of how it's phrased or if it's phrased better with better answers.

Comment: I'd give you an extra +1 for "don't take it personally" if I could. I don't look at who's first, I just compare contents and quality. I feel these are roughly equal in quality with no particular edge either way.

Answer (score 4):

As hard as it is to take (Don't get all hard on yourself for posting a duplicate, although you seem to be taking it in stride. I posted what some think is a duplicate just yesterday.) I think the question **with the best answer(s)** should be the one to remain open, regardless of which question was posted first. If the goal of our community is to provide the internet with stellar information on a variety of topics, the best information needs to come up first on a Google search.

Sometimes we will be the one to post a question that gets the best answer(s), but sometimes it will be another question that is the highest quality. That is the one that should remain open.