# Should the Dementors question be reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, vote-to-reopen

Should this question be reopened?

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128502/where-do-dementors-come-from

It was closed by two users (Jason Baker and Slytherincess) as a duplicate of [Did Ekrizdis create the Dementors?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120595/did-ekrizdis-create-the-dementors), but at least one user (hedgehog, the OP) contends that the answers to the existing question don't answer the new one and therefore it is not a duplicate. (For full information, another question mentioned in comments as a possible duplicate was [How are Dementors created/born?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8919/how-are-dementors-created-born))

Since the question is currently locked due to [other issues](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/128502/revisions), no non-moderator can vote to reopen it. You'll be able to VTRO when it's unlocked, if appropriate, but I'd like to get a sense of the community's opinion now since it might impact on the discussion [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9648/rules-for-a-duplicate-post-deletion).

### Is this question really a duplicate, or should it be reopened?

Comment: were do they comefrom, and how are they born seem the same to me? id vote to close it again

Comment: **Please consider the body of the question as well as its title when making your decision.** Also, don't pay too much attention to its negative score; I suspect most of those downvotes are due to the OP's attitude rather than the quality of the post.

Comment: (Btw @Himarm, the above comment isn't directed at you - just a general note. You were quick enough to get in before I finished typing it :-) )

Comment: @Himarm - "seem" because you didn't peruse the contents of the question or its answers, as Rand said. I expanded in my answer.

Comment: About tags: I think this post is an argument for renaming [meta-tag:vote-to-reopen] to [meta-tag:reopening-questions]. This post seems more like a question about reopening rather than an informal vote to reopen.

Comment: @anaranjada Sure, you might be right. Remind me another day though - I've got more to worry about than meta tags just now.

Comment: \[tag:tag-pedantry] :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Absolutely should be reopened (and if the question wasn't locked, I would have now undupe-hammered it and fixed it up).

***It should be reopened, albiet refocused on what is now question #4 in a list of 4***.

- It is NOT a duplicate of " [Did Ekrizdis create the Dementors?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120595/did-ekrizdis-create-the-dementors) ".

  The question itself only asks about ONE plausible theory of Dementor origins, and the answers don't conclusively and exaustively cover ALL plausible theories. As such, **that question's answers do not adequately address the question under consideration**.

  <sub>Yes, it is possible that someone might post an exaustive answer to Ekrizids Q, which would answer "Did Ekrizids" with "***This*** is the definitive origin, and it is NOT Ekrizids", and such an answer would then address Hedgehog's question. But such an answer is NOT posted there now.</sub>
- It is NOT a duplicate of " [How are Dementors created/born?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8919/how-are-dementors-created-born) "

  That question's title may mislead one at first glance, but it is about creation of an individual dementor being, NOT about creation/origin of Dementors as a species, and as such **its answers also in no way address the question under consideration**.

Having said that, SQB's answer makes a valid point, and 3 sub-questions out of 4 can and likely should be deleted, leaving only "*What is their story, did they get created by someone or just started existing similar as to giants?*". The other 3 can then be reposted as separate questions, but at least some of them are indeed dupes (such as #1)

Comment: What about sqb's point that its still 4 questions?

Comment: @Himarm - Quite trivial to edit out 3 extraneous ones :). Rand was specifically asking about delicateness, so I chose to address that as the actually important and hard to fix issue.

Comment: The fact that the dupe doesn't exhaustively deal with every theory seems an excellent cause to open that question up for more answers (perhaps by levying a bounty?) but it's not cause for opening this one back up, even ignoring the fact that it's not sensibly scoped.

Comment: @Himarm - updated my answer to address your point specifically

Comment: @Valorum - the fact that the alleged dupe - as a QUESTION - wasn't centered on, and wasn't trying to, get the exaustive answer  - means that it shouldn't be turned into a question it was never attempting to be. It was a great question with good answers. It just wasn't the question that this user was trying to ask.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - I can see your point, I just don't agree with it. Both dupey questions deal with pretty much all we know about the genesis of these creatures. A question which asks much the same again will get much the same answer from much the same sources. I've gotta fall with Slytherincess on this one.

Comment: @Valorum - as a matter of fact, if you WANT them to be dupes with exaustive answer, the newer question should be chosen as the one to stay open, as it is more generic; and the exaustive answer should be posted to it

Comment: @anaranjada - "Vote for the post, not the user". I don't care one whit what user's behavior was or is; I only care what the merits of the post are (I'll leave aside that I chose to leave the site in small part because of abuse of people like OP and subsequent piling onto them).

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - There's certain an argument for *merging* the two questions but it's hard to see how you'd manage it without the consent of the OP. I'd vote for it though.

Comment: @Valorum - Merging might be a solution, but it is generally mainly seems to be employed where both questions have great but somewhat-duplicate answers, so the answers aren't split between them. I don't think it is used when one question is a proper small subset of another, as is the case here. Not sure what the rules are, this is just from anecdotal observation

Comment: @anaranjada you know it is not always on what the other says but on how he says it, if it would be DVK-in-exile which i have much respect for, that said: i think this should be edited for these reasons, i would totally accept his opinion and his edit.So to sum up, I would totally accept if DVK-in-exile would apply his edits as he sees fit on my post, whenever the opening of it would be. But even though, i still believe that a part of the moderators here have overstepped on their authorities in this matter and possible on some other and I will see into it, everyone of the community has a word.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile I didnt get upset because someone just closed my post, i got upset because someone closed my post, because he Thought so that it was a dublicate... he didnt provide any additional information to confirm his words and didnt accept any other opinion, i was never given the chance or asked to edit my question or explain why it is not a dublicate, thats why i got upset. I personally dont like this behaviour and this is how all started.. :)

Comment: I'd say the least dupey of the four questions is the gender one; the other three all seem to be covered by one of the two older questions.

Comment: @dvk-in-exile if we run "exhaustive" answers beyond what we know from canon and WoG doesn't turn either the question or answer into a POB and thus be off-topic? I only say this because I feel the two questions already cover all we know based on canon.

Comment: @Skooba so you are claiming that you, having knowledge of all canon information, you can guarantee that there is no other information according to my question that someone could know and share/answer..?

Comment: @hedgehog let me call my lawyer.....

Comment: @hedgehog - You have to take on trust that gold tag badge holders have a solid grasp on what information is available in the canon. While I happily admit that there's the possibility that there's an unheard-of source (such as an interview that hasn't come to light or a recent twit)  that's still no reason to continually re-ask something that's already been answered. If you feel the dupe isn't complete, you can post a bounty.

Comment: @Valorum but it wasnt asked man, the only thing that was asked, was if a specific person created them, and the answer was specific on if that guy made them, no mention of who actually or how they did get created... even so, i understand that gold badge users have these badges for a specific reason, which i respec, but still you have to admit that it cannot be that they are always correct, after all we are all humans and we make mistakes, point is after we do them, to understand them. :)

Comment: @Valorum In this case it's more complicated as we have one HP gold tag badge holder closing the question, another agreeing that it's a duplicate, and a third saying it's NOT a duplicate. All we need now is alexwlchan to complete the confusion!

Comment: @Randal'Thor i suppose i am the third person :p though DVK researched it and also agrees with me :) (and as far as i can see, his 200k rep means something as well as these gold badges.)

Comment: @hedgehog Yep, DVK was the third person I was referring to. The fact that he disagrees with Richard and Slytherincess on this (all three have HP gold badges and very high rep) complicates the issue somewhat.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - DVK's contention seems to not be that this is a dupe, but rather that the older question is a dupe of this one.

Comment: @valorum not quite.  I think they aren't dupes.  But if they have to be dupes then yes this one is less close able.  But I'd rather see them separate

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - Since reopening them will simply result in the same users rehashing the same answers, doing *nothing* seems the far simpler course of action.

Comment: @Valorum so you are looking for the simpler solution for you? hmmmm i think you should be looking for the best solution not the easiest....

Comment: @hedgehog - As I said to DVK, I can get behind merging them, but I'm loathe to allow the creation of a dupe (with the consequence that the older question could get closed as a dupe of *your question*) simply because the new question is 'wider'. The mob have spoken and seem in favour of leaving it closed; +5 "*because it is a dupe"* and +2 "*because it's poorly scoped*" vs. 0 points for "*it's not a dupe"*.  If you think there's canon that we're missing, sling a bounty on the original question.

Comment: @Valorum but if the questions is refrained to : "How dementors were created" and ask only that in overal, then i guess its not a dupe?  or at least, let me delete the questions and remake it in a correct way...... i was never given this chance you know.... which i should have...

Comment: I agree that this wasn't handled well. By the same token, your own conduct was really quite odd and certainly didn't help matters

Answer (score 5):

### Leave Closed as Duplicate

**If the question was not a duplicate of**

[Did Ekrizdis create the Dementors?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120595/did-ekrizdis-create-the-dementors)

**It is surely a duplicate of**

[How are Dementors created/born?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8919/how-are-dementors-created-born)

A common thought, although not 100% enforced rule is that an answer can make a question a duplicate. Based on the answers given in the older questions, any answers given to the new question will be the same.

---

From a different point on view... being the OP for the first linked question, I had to carefully select and word the question I was asking because it too was almost closed as a duplicate of the second question.

Additionally, while no user is all-powerful or all-knowing  Richard (Valorum) and Slytherincess are `gold-badge` holders and therefore would be considered the cream of the crop experts in that field (at least by SE standards). Their knowledge of the subject should lend some credence and weight to the close votes.

Comment: Agreed. It's a dupe. As a gold tag badge holder in that topic, if I saw it in the queue or on the front page I'd have no hesitation in immediately closing it as such.

Comment: Who's this Richard?

Comment: @Valorum I have your new name in the parentheses... You can't hide with 185k rep by just changing your name!

Comment: @Valorum You can't play that game. You are neither Dana, nor Zuul.

Comment: I'm also quite offended at being referred to as "not all knowing".

Comment: @Valorum I will never forgive you by being 5 seconds quicker to an answer that *one time*....

Comment: @Skooba - There's no point being a day late and a dollar short, as my dear old granny used to say.

Comment: @Valorum - read my answer please. I actually read and analyzed the contents of the questions (unlike - it seems - this post's author) and the second link is not in any way, shape or form even smells of a duplicate (and the first link isn't really a duplicate either, though it at least has valid arguments for it)

Comment: @Skooba Does this answer take into consideration all four questions in the original post?

Comment: @Rand al'thor I would say it covers all the questions directly or indirectly based on the information we have from canon and WoG. Anything beyond that would be POB/speculation

Answer (score 2):

**No**

Not because it may or may not be a duplicate, but because it's asking *at least* 4 questions at once:

> 1. **Where do Dementors come from?**
>
> Also, unexplainable is:
>
> 2. Do they have a gender? (male/female)
> 3. (...) how do they actually reproduce?
> 4. What is their story, did they get created by someone or just started existing similar as to giants?

Comment: So we should re-open it so that we can reclose it for the correct reason?

Comment: @Valorum basically its an all around disaster!

Comment: @Himarm - Agreed. Also at least two of those supplementary questions are also dupes, one answered by the question it's been marked as a dupe of and the other a dupe of another question.

Comment: What about if questions 1 and 4 (and possibly 3) were removed, to make the question less broad?

Comment: Are any of those questions not dupes? Could the question be edited to limit it to one question that has not been previously asked?

Comment: The only question not a direct dupe is "do they have a gender"

Comment: @anaranjada - We could, but that would conflict with what the OP was asking in the first place.

Comment: Then SQB should someone ask me to revise and edit the post Q??? Instead of marking instantly as a duplicate?

Comment: @hedgehog Yes, but 3 out of 4 questions you asked _were_ duplicates. I think your best option is asking about the gender of dementors in a new question and let this one be. Duplicates aren't a bad thing, because they're other entry points for people looking for an answer.

Comment: @hedgehog Yes, someone should probably have left a comment asking you to revise and edit the question. I'm hoping that when it's unlocked, you (or someone else) will do exactly that, and then perhaps it can be reopened.

Comment: @hedgehog keep in mind that being closed as a duplicate isn't punishment or a condemnation. It's just a marker that it has been asked before and we should continue from there, to avoid repeating ourselves.

Comment: @Randal'Thor excuse me both of you, but in my opinion prevention is better than the cure, really though, there should be a guideline, on when and under which conditions someone can mark a question as a duplicate (e.g. providing exact and plenty of evidence, not just a link saying its a dupe of that).... because dont forget, someone is NOT guilty until its proved otherwise...

Comment: @hedgehog Asking a duplicate question isn't a crime; "guilty" is far too strong a word to use. You might be right that some people close as duplicate too easily, but that's what reopen votes are for! Let's be patient; I'm sure we can sort this out :-) By the way, you might be interested to see the revision history of [this post](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/128645/revisions), which was closed as duplicate and then reopened when the OP edited his question after getting feedback in comments. That's the system working as it should.

Comment: @Randal'Thor i know that normally this is the case, but man why it cant be that someone can kindly ask to refrain the question, or else it should be marked as duplicate, because if someone spends time to look around if the actual question exists and then make the question and someone closes it as duplicate his action can be interpreted as saying that the other didnt good enough search before posting, and in the intellectual world this could be a kind of offensive. I hope you get what i mean.btw my example, was like what happens in the court, you are not guilty until you are proven to be.