# Are duplicate questions encouraged?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

To improve meta search efficiency does SE encourage a "substantially reworded question" which has a common answer? To such a point that I could create a question myself and mark it duplicate for this purpose?

I can't find this directly answered, but the tone of the policy statements place a stigma against duplicate questions.

A comment led me to believe duplicates serve a purpose and remain searchable even after closing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No intentionally creating a duplicate is not encouraged for whatever reason. Duplicates can be good in that they aid searches and a well worded duplicate is still a good question but that does not mean you should post a question you know is a duplicate.

In short you should try and avoid posting any question you know will or should be closed.

Comment: The logic? It would improve the quality here.. On its face that seems contradictory

Comment: @VogonPoet No it wouldn’t improve the quality here at all. Intentionally creating duplicates is likely to lead to downvotes which is going to degrade the quality.

Comment: If so, [this is not as it should be](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9979/are-users-encouraged-to-downvote-questions-for-being-duplicates/9980#9980). This is a systemic problem.

Comment: @VogonPoet there’s a world of difference between asking a question that turns out to be a duplicate and intentionally asking a duplicate.