# Why are some of my questions marked as duplicate when they are not?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

If you want to see what questions they are: I've deleted them. Maybe some of you know them, and maybe some of you here can say they really are duplicates. There are some that I didn't delete.

My question is, there are some of my questions that were marked as duplicates of another question from another user, *which had a big difference and doesn't answer my question because my question is different*. It really pisses me off how some of my questions are suddenly marked as duplicates when they are not.

NOTE: If someone will comment or answer that it is because my topic has similarities, then it should be related not duplicate. And the way my question easily becomes a duplicate when these questions have big differences is so unreasonable. And the question they linked **doesn't answer my question.** How can that be considered as a duplicate?

Comment: Since you deleted them, we can't see if the duplication was fair or not. If you. If you objected the duplication, why didn't you ask on meta earlier? Regardless, the burden of proving that a question is not a duplicate lies on asker; in future, try to word your titles and questions in a way that people won't want to close them as duplicates. Avoiding using certain keywords will help, as will putting a *small* caveat at the bottom, stating **why** exactly your question is not a duplicate. Notice I said **small**, as in a sentence, not a paragraph.

Comment: Since you've deleted them, it's practically impossible to see what you're referring to. Questions like this need ***examples***.

Comment: I shall repeat my earlier advice. Since you have two issues here; 1) Poor English spelling and grammar and 2) A habit of asking duplicate questions, both could be immediately helped by ***Asking the question in chat***. You'd get advice on improving the language used as well as support in searching for potential duplicates that you might have missed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are questions considered duplicates although they ask different things?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3194/why-are-questions-considered-duplicates-although-they-ask-different-things)

Comment: See also; [Why is the close-as-duplicate policy so aggressive, and should we change it?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6944/why-is-the-close-as-duplicate-policy-so-aggressive-and-should-we-change-it)

Comment: You've posted a total of six questions which have been closed as duplicate and later deleted: [one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/150334/31394), [two](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/149671/31394), [three](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/149610/31394), [four](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/148473/31394), [five](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/146487/31394), [six](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/146048/31394). Now that we have links to the questions you're asking about, I'm reopening this meta post as it's no longer "unclear what you're asking". I'll also post an answer shortly.

Comment: Have you edited your questions to specifically explain in what way they are not duplicates (and in what way existing answers on alleged duplucate fail to answer your question)?

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To yes I edited some of them when it was already marked as duplicate. I then explained the *why's*, proving that it's not a duplicate and the linked question doesn't answer my question. But it was still closed as duplicate, so I just deleted them.

Comment: @DVK You can see all this user's deleted duplicate posts by checking the links in my answer. Judge for yourself whether you think any of them shouldn't have been closed. With your gold HP tag badge, you could even reopen them while they're deleted if you feel it's merited.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I believe some of them are not yet deleted. I wouldn't even post this question if I don't have something wrong to argue with :)

Comment: I'm sorry for saying this, but I feel insulted by your comment.

Comment: @Randal'Thor you don't even need to bother to reply. I'm just gonna switch into another website where there are more users who'll well welcome newcomers, unlike here. That's everything I know, I'm not wasting my time anymore in here, bye.

Comment: @BookStriker Which comment? I apologise - it wasn't my intention to be insulting. (Assuming you're addressing me and not someone else.)

Comment: @BookStriker Edited my answer to (sort of) address the non-deleted duplicates.

Comment: Something to keep in mind: just about every user who's been around for a while ends up posting a duplicate question. Duplicate questions aren't bad. If your question is closed as a duplicate, then perhaps comment on an answer of the dupe target that best matches your question and ask for clarification or additional information on a particular point.

Answer (score 12):

You've posted a total of **six** questions which have been closed as duplicate and later deleted. (Each of them was closed either by a moderator or the holder of a gold [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) tag badge. While not conclusive proof, this is at least *strong evidence* that your questions really were duplicates - people with unilateral closing powers don't tend to exercise them much except in very clear cases.)

1. [Difference of a Muggle and a Squib](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/150334/31394) - see **[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm6Nh.png)**.

   You asked what the difference is between a Muggle and a Squib. Your question was closed as a duplicate of [Is a Squib a Muggle?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14526/31394), which is asking more or less the same thing and whose answers address the differences between Muggles and Squibs.
2. [The origin of the house-elves](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/149671/31394) - see **[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFIoL.png)**.

   You asked about the lineage, ancestry, and species history of house elves. Your question was closed as a duplicate of [Where do house elves come from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/144711/31394), which is also asking about the origin of house elves. Its answer is somewhat unsatisfactory, but if you want a better answer, the best way to ask for one is to [set a bounty](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on the question rather than posting a duplicate.
3. [The power of the four historical artefacts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/149610/31394) - see **[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cXec.png)**.

   You asked what powers are possessed by the artefacts of the four Hogwarts founders, specifically the Hufflepuff cup and the Slytherin locket. Your question was closed as a duplicate of [What powers did the Hufflepuff cup, the Slytherin locket, and the Ravenclaw diadem possess?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/60947/31394), which is also asking about the powers of these artefacts and has a good answer covering the diadem, the cup, and the locket each in turn.
4. [Did Voldemort only manage to obtain 5 horcruxes before haunting Harry in Godric's Hollow?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/148473/31394) - see **[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TES0H.png)**.

   You asked how many Horcruxes Voldemort had made by the time he went to Godric's Hollow to kill baby Harry. Your question was closed as a duplicate of [Was Voldemort still in the process of making his Horcruxes when he went to Godric's Hollow?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/74246/31394), which is asking exactly the same thing. Neither of its answers quite address the point, but again, that's not a good reason to post a duplicate.
5. [Any theories at all of a boggart's identities?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/146487/31394) - see **[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qs0a.png)**.

   I'm not completely sure what your question is here, but you seem to be asking what a boggart would look like in its 'natural' state, rather than when facing someone with a fear it could mimic. Your question was closed as a duplicate of [What shape would a boggart take if a person doesn't fear anything](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/61026/31394), which is asking something very similar and whose answer addresses your question. Another possible dupe target would have been [Could Mad-Eye Moody See the Natural State of a Boggart With His Magical Eye?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7479/31394), which was linked to in the comments.
6. [How do the wizard blood came out from generations to generations?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/146048/31394) - see **[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKhX8.png)**.

   Again your question is a little unclear, but you seem to be asking about the nature of 'magical blood' in the Potterverse and how it spreads. Your question was closed as a duplicate of [Where did the "Magic Blood" of the Harry Potter Universe Originate From?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18783/31394), a popular dupe target which asks about the origins and nature of 'magical blood'.

I hope I've now successfully demonstrated that each of your deleted dupe-closed questions really was a duplicate. One further point to note: **[please don't delete your questions just because they're duplicates](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7944/31394)**. A duplicate of a good question is often a good question in its own right, and such posts often aid searchability and make it easier for people in the future to find the answer to their question.

---

You've also posted **nine** questions which have been closed as duplicate and *not* since deleted; these can be found listed [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A74547+duplicate%3A1). Since these are easily searchable even by non-moderators, I'll let someone else (perhaps someone with more expertise in *Harry Potter* than I) go through them to check whether they all really are duplicates. Worry not - we have enough gold [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) tag badge holders (six) that any which have been wrongly closed should get reopened quickly, especially now that you've brought them to the attention of meta.