# Why are people interested in undeleting this question?

Tags: discussion, support

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180820/931

I had deleted this question after it was marked duplicate and I really hadn't done much research before asking it.

But, about an hour ago, some users undeleted it. I am curious to know why.

Does it really add any value to the site seeing it doesn't have any answer?

I deleted it again because system would delete it anyway because it has negative votes and zero answers.

Comment: It widens the net, therefore useful. Even if it’s in a topic people don’t find interesting or practical.

Comment: If you're concerned about rep, you can flag your post and ask moderators to disassociate it from your user account

Comment: Don't flag the post, you need to email SE directly. *"Only CMs can disassociate a post from an account. Please use the "contact" link at the bottom of the site if you still want to do this."*

Comment: Considering that the post is so highly downvoted, has no answer, and you can even earn badge for doing so, I don't see what the user did wrong. That being said, there is precedence for undeleting duplicates, throw in the standard "you dont 'own' your posts'....

Comment: @Edlothiad If you're referring to the [good dupe philosophy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/), no, it doesn't. There's no distinct phrasing that would make this question more discoverable than the other one.

Comment: @jpmc26 given one cites a completely different article that the other doesn't, anyone searching for the text in that article may be lead to that question and therefor the dupe target. It definitely widens the net.

Comment: @Edlothiad Can you provide an example search that demonstrates this?

Comment: @jpmc26 I think the 22 answer upvotes are evidence enough of community opinion.

Comment: @Edlothiad The upvoted answer proposes a possible explanation. It does not assert that the reason supposed is adequate or being applied correctly. In fact, the answerer explicitly notes they do not object to it being deleted, so by your logic, the user should be allowed to delete their post. Additionally, I didn't ask about community opinion. I asked for a mere shred of evidence of your claim (one of the kind I provided on my comment on the answer).

Comment: @jpmc26 your comment under the answer limits the search only to our on-site search, the broadening of this net isn't only on _this_ site, but on any search engines as well. The phrasing in the question bodies are significantly different, while on the same topic, which evidently broadens the net on search engines coming to the site. Additionally, the user no longer own the post, its owned by SE. It broadens the net, if the OP dislikes the loss in rep they should do more research. Simple

Comment: @Edlothiad Then stop dodging the question and come up with a link to a Google search. I chose the site search there because I know the site search is *vastly* inferior to Google. The notion of "good duplication" doesn't mean we should endlessly leave every last possible wording lying around. I also find it ironic that you try to defend your point with upvotes on an answer that disagrees with you while ignoring what the downvotes on the question suggest about its value. Also, *no*, SE does **not** own the post's content. SE requires you to *license* the post. Not the same thing *at all*.

Comment: @jpmc26 - Searching for [""Is Albus Dumbledore gay?""](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=i92SWtqfKNS0gAaaz5CwCg&q=%22Is+Albus+Dumbledore+gay%3F%22&oq=%22Is+Albus+Dumbledore+gay%3F%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1l3.8120.8809.0.9471.2.2.0.0.0.0.85.151.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.148...0i30k1j0i8i30k1.0.qjAJh28dLbU) get you the dupe question as #2 on the list. By comparison, the original question is #3 (largely because it's linked to the dupe question) So there's a distinct search benefit in having both questions undeleted, even if one is closed.

Comment: just FYI, for the OP's benefit, questions closed as dupes are _not_ deleted just because they're low scoring or unanswered, specifically because SE considers them beneficial to have around.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Probably because **[deleting duplicate questions is discouraged](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7944/33591)** here.

We have a very clear meta consensus, and it's even tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). To quote from the question:

> If I post a question after searching and determining it hasn't been asked. And later find out, on my own or by a fellow user that the question is a possible duplicate. Is it encouraged to delete the questions, or should I wait for the consensus of users that vote to close it ?

And the answer states very clearly

> ***No***
>   ***DO NOT DO THIS***

Personally, I wouldn't vote to undelete a duplicate that's been downvoted so heavily, but I can see why people would.

Comment: Key phrase: "after searching and determining it hasn't been asked." The duplicate is readily available in the search: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=dumbledore+gay, and the OP *explicitly* states they didn't do enough research before posting. I'd be surprised if the dupe target wasn't in the suggestion list if you tried to ask it now. The OP's question doesn't make finding the dupe target easier and got closed. Downvotes aside, it doesn't offer any value.