# Why was this question closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, closing-questions, duplicate-questions

[Are human-looking Jedi/Sith like Palpatine and the Skywalkers the same (human) species as non-Force users?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48498/are-human-looking-jedi-sith-like-palpatine-and-skywalkers-humans)

This question was recently marked as a duplicate. Two things bother me:

- This question has an accepted answer. 2 years later a [duplicate question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110205/are-the-humans-in-the-star-wars-galaxy-really-humans) was asked which the community failed to close as a duplicate. And now the original question was closed as a duplicate.
- The other question has no accepted or thorough answer and yet the question with an accepted and thorough answer is a duplicate of the other. What kind of logic is that?

**Why was [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48498/are-human-looking-jedi-sith-like-palpatine-and-skywalkers-humans) closed as a duplicate of [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110205/are-the-humans-in-the-star-wars-galaxy-really-humans) instead of the other way around?**

Comment: While the newer question is slightly broader (all human-like characters vs. Jedi only), the answer on the older is better, I think. Good to bring this up.

Comment: Perhaps a slight edit to yours to clarify that you're asking whether Jedi humans *in the Star Wars galaxy"  are the same species as non-Jedi humans *in the Star Wars Galaxy*? As it stands DVK is answering his **own question** (the one he asked in the comment that you didn't address) rather than yours.

Comment: Please clarify explicitly if you're asking "is Palpatine human as Han Solo" or "is Palpatine human as people posting on SFF". The answer to your Meta question changes based on that.

Answer (score 4):

I spotted a fully canon source that directly addressed the question of whether Star Wars humans are the same as Earth humans. I did a search and found *two* questions that asked essentially the same question. Rather than answering both with a copy/paste answer, I answered one and made the other a duplicate.

My logic was that your question, although containing the slightly better *answer*, is a subset of the wider question of whether the humans in the Star Wars universe are, per se the same as humans from Earth.

We [don't necessarily close the younger question as a dupe](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/should-we-always-close-the-newer-question-as-the-duplicate?rq=1) nor are we expected to close one as a dupe of another [simply because it has a slightly more highly upvoted answer or an accepted answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10212/why-was-an-older-accepted-story-id-question-closed-as-a-duplicate-of-a-newer-on?rq=1).

---

It would probably be wise for a moderator to merge DVKs answer over (to the non-dupe) since it contains some interesting points, if not much in the way of canon evidence.

Answer (score 4):

Your question can be interpreted one of two different ways:

1. Are Sith that look like Han Solo the same species of The Galaxy Far Far Away "human" as Han Solo?
2. Are Sith that look "human" the Homo Sapient species from Earth?

I specifically asked you to clarify what you meant in a comment in 2014 (which you never did):

> *Just to clarify: by "Homo Sapiens" and "humans" you mean humans from Star Wars galaxy, correct? (e.g. those living on Coruscant/Corellia/Tattooine/etc....) – DVK-on-Ahch-To Jan 22 '14 at 13:26*

If you meant #1 (are they TGFFA humans); the two questions are NOT duplicate (nor does Valorum's answer on the other question answers yours). OTOH, my answer, which you accepted, answers it fully.

If you meant #2, then they are duplicates. I will assume that this wasn't what you meant **because you accepted my answer, which in no way discussed Earth humans**, despite your question wording mentioning Homo Sapient - which I assume was just bad wording.

As such, absent clarification from you:

- I edited your question to specifically be about TGFFA humans and not Earth humans.
- I re-opened it since neither the question NOR either answer are now duplicate.

Comment: Having said that, if what you wanted to ask was "are they Earth humans" an NOT "are they TGFFA humans", feel free to edit your question to reflect that fully, and flag for someone to re-close it as a duplicate - at which point I will re-post my answer on a question that it actually CAN answer.

Comment: See further edit; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48498/are-human-looking-jedi-sith-like-palpatine-and-skywalkers-humans. If OP rolls that back, we'll definitely need to reclose