# Which one of them should have been marked as a duplicate of the other?

Tags: discussion

[Do Morpheus and his crew kill potential Ones?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144725/do-morpheus-and-his-crew-kill-potential-ones?noredirect=1#comment369135_144725) vs [Why did Cypher say they were going to kill Neo?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73363/why-did-cypher-say-they-were-going-to-kill-neo)

The latter (asked two years ago) was marked as a duplicate of the former (recent). I don't see anything new in the recent answers that was not covered in the old question. So why was the older one marked as a duplicate?

Comment: I think neither. They're not duplicates -- one asks why Cypher said something, and the other asks if the crew kills potential Ones. Those are totally different questions, albeit they center around the same quote. If I thought they were duplicates I wouldn't have answered the new one. The link in my recent answer to my older answer was more of an aside.

Comment: Good point @Null.

Do continue what Fuzzy asked, I've always taken chronological order as a priority.  Now if there was significant, sudden, and relevant work in the newer question/item, then that would be a factor to keep it open.  Although, if marking an item as a duplicate doesn't obscure information or access to adding to the Q&A, then you could still at least mark it to show that it came second.  Probably another situation to measure the important and capability of the system to decide which action to take.

Comment: Can't moderators _merge_ the two questions (with answers)? I haven't been a moderator in any SE site, but I believe I've read it's possible.

Comment: Interestingly this is exactly what you've just done with a three year old answer of mine! The message says "This question already has an answer here:" on the *older* question, which is misleading. I think it would be fine if the banner was more neutral, such as "This question also has an answer here:" and if duplicates had reciprocal links, or if questions could be merged (though that would only work if they were very clearly the same thing) Story-identification would probably be fit for merging most of the time.

Comment: It seemed appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking as the first close-voter<sup>1</sup>, I agonized over this one.

Ultimately, I decided to vote to close because I felt that [KutuluMike's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/144727/31051) to the newer question was more complete. I particularly liked the mention of the supplemental materials, which I felt was missing from [Null's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/73372/31051) to the older question, and most relevantly the observation that Neo isn't the first "One" that Morpheus has tested out<sup>2</sup>.

At this point I'm also going to refer to our previous (and, I understand, not-uncontroversial) discussion [Should we always close the newer question as the duplicate?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4744/31051); I don't believe it's necessarily the best option to close the newer of two questions. Others may disagree, but that's my stance.

### Should it have been closed at all?

This section is mainly in response to [Null's comment](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10328/which-one-of-them-should-have-been-marked-as-a-duplicate-of-the-other/10329#comment30651_10328) on this meta question:

> They're not duplicates -- one asks why Cypher said something, and the other asks if the crew kills potential Ones.

Okay, *mea culpa*: there's a subtlety there I hadn't considered when I cast my vote. But I do still think they're intensely related questions, and my gut reaction upon reading the older isn't "What is Cypher's motivation here?" but "Is Cypher saying they're *literally* going to kill him?"

That being said, I do appreciate that another perspective exists. I stand by my vote, but I'm not going to throw a tantrum now that it's been re-opened.

---

<sup>1</sup> Though I will point out that I voted [from the queue](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/93797), so I [didn't make the initial determination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60ZEo.png)

<sup>2</sup> I would have liked the answer a lot more if those materials had been quoted directly, but that's a different conversation entirely

Comment: Close-as-duplicate is always about *duplicate questions*, not questions that end up with *duplicate answers*.

Comment: @R.. That's a [long-standing](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3194/31051) and [contentious](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6944/31051) discussion on this site

Comment: @R.. That might be true for other sites, but it certainly isn't on this one.