# Which story ID question should we close as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

This old question [Story where the hero ends up having his eyelids removed and being hooked up to some kind of virtual reality machine](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137606/story-where-the-hero-ends-up-having-his-eyelids-removed-and-being-hooked-up-to-s) has a good answer but it was only accepted via a comment under the question.

This new question [1950s short story about a man awakening from suspended animation in the near future roughly the same and gets lobotomized, then gets a VR future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258987/1950s-short-story-about-a-man-awakening-from-suspended-animation-in-the-near-fut) also has a good answer and actually got accepted.

(Just for completeness, there is a third even older one [Short story about addictive games and virtual realities](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52371/short-story-about-addictive-games-and-virtual-realities/52826#52826) which has no sort of acceptance at all - it may not be the correct answer in this case). Just to be clear, this one can't be closed.

Does the community have a preference of which one of the accepted answers to close as a duplicate? I was about to close the older one (good, but not formally accepted) but realized it might be good to ask in meta.

Comment: "dupe the newer to the older" Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this instance it doesn't really seem to matter. Both are fine questions with fine answers. Our general policy is to [***dupe the worse to the better***](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/should-we-always-close-the-newer-question-as-the-duplicate?rq=1) with no reference to the age of the answers. That being said, where one is very new  and all other things being broadly equal, I'd personally dupe the newer to the older since the newer one was only a few hours old.

As regards your third example, note that we [don't close unconfirmed questions as dupes](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/20774). By extension, we also don't dupe confirmed questions with unconfirmed ones